# Difficulty calling infromation between functions and structures

Tags: c++

I am working with structures in my class right now, and in this we are asked to  create a structure with the four variables listed, and allow user to input number for each which we record and find the total yearly rainfall, average per month, highest, and lowest overall (and their occurrences). My main issue is getting data from the getInfo function for my getHot function to find the months with the high temp.

```
 #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

//weather structure

    struct WeatherData
    {
        double rainfall;
        double highestTemperature;
        double lowestTemperature;
        double averageTemperature;
    };
    //prototypes
    WeatherData getInfo();
    double getHot(WeatherData *);
    double getCold();

    int main()
    {
        WeatherData seattle;
        enum monthName { JANUARY, FEBRUARY, MARCH, APRIL, MAY, JUNE, JULY, AUGUST, SEPTEMBER, OCTOBER, NOVEMBER, DECEMBER };
        double totalRainfall = 0;
        double maxTemperature;
        double minTemperature;
        double averageTemperature;

        seattle = getInfo();
        for (int index = JANUARY; index <= DECEMBER; index++)
        {
            totalRainfall += seattle.rainfall;
        }

        seattle.averageTemperature = (totalRainfall) / 12;
        getHot(& seattle);

        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    // My getInfo function records all the information from user
    WeatherData getInfo()
    {
        WeatherData tempData;
        double totalRainfall = 0;
        enum monthName { JANUARY, FEBRUARY, MARCH, APRIL, MAY, JUNE, JULY, AUGUST, SEPTEMBER, OCTOBER, NOVEMBER, DECEMBER };
        for (int index = JANUARY; index <= DECEMBER; index++)
        {
            cout << "Enter the total rainfall in month " << (index+1) << " (greater than or equal to zero) : " << endl;
            cin >> tempData.rainfall;
            cout << "rainfall " << tempData.rainfall;
            while (tempData.rainfall < 0)
            {
                cout << "This is an invalid input, enter a number equal to or greater than zero : " << endl;
                cin >> tempData.rainfall;

            }
            cout << "Enter the highest temperature in month " << (index + 1) << " (less than or equal to 140) : " << endl;
            cin >> tempData.highestTemperature;
            while (tempData.highestTemperature > 140)
            {
                cout << "This is an invalid input, enter a number equal to or less than 140 : " << endl;
                cin >> tempData.highestTemperature;

            }
            cout << "highest " << tempData.highestTemperature;
            cout << "Enter the lowest temperature in month " << (index + 1) << " (greater than or equal to -100) : " << endl;
            cin >> tempData.lowestTemperature;
            while (tempData.lowestTemperature < -100)
            {
                cout << "This is an invalid input, enter a number equal to or greater than -100 : " << endl;
                cin >> tempData.lowestTemperature;
            }
            cout << "lowest " << tempData.lowestTemperature;
            totalRainfall += tempData.rainfall;
        }
        tempData.averageTemperature = (tempData.lowestTemperature + tempData.highestTemperature) / 2;
        return tempData;
    }
    //having difficulty here figuring out how to get the contents of getInfo and return it to the main 
    double getHot(WeatherData * getInfo)
    {
        double highTemp = 0;
        for (int index = 0; index <= 12; index++)
        {
            if (getInfo->highestTemperature > highTemp)
                highTemp = getInfo->highestTemperature;
        }
            //return highTemp to function
        cout << " The maximum temperature is : " << highTemp << endl;
        return highTemp;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your getInfo method doesn't record data for all 12 months: it keeps overwriting them.

So you'd need to change your seattle variable so that it can hold the data for all 12 months,something like that:

```
WeatherData seattle[12];
...

GetInfo(&seattle);
....

void GetInfo(WeatherData* theData){
...
for (int index = JANUARY; index <= DECEMBER; index++)
        {
            cout << "Enter the total rainfall in month " << (index+1) << " (greater than or equal to zero) : " << endl;
            cin >> theData[index].rainfall;

(etc)
```

And fix getHot:

```
double getHot(WeatherData * getInfo)
{
    double highTemp = 0;
    double highIndex = -1;
    for (int index = 0; index <= 12; index++)
    {
        if (getInfo->highestTemperature > highTemp) {
            highTemp = getInfo->highestTemperature;
            highIndex = index;
        }
    }

    cout << " The maximum temperature is : " << getInfo[highIndex].highTemp << endl;
    cout << " the hottest month is: " << highIndex << endl;
    cout << " The rainfall in the hottest month is: " << getInfo[highIndex].rainfall << endl;

    return highTemp; //if you still want to return highTemp
}
```